# iOS Vendor ID changed

Tags: ios, keychain, vendor, bundle-identifier

About a month ago, everything was working fine, I could install my app from TestFlight, from AppStore and Vendor ID was always the same. I have more applications installed from same vendor. But now, like a week ago, I installed TestFlight version, actually updated (I have not uninstalled it) and day after update, Vendor ID just changed. I am storing my Vendor ID to keychain for service with unique string and account is `bundleIdentifier`. `bundleIdentifier` is same, unique string is always same and Vendor ID has changed unexpectedly without uninstalling application. I am using this for getting identifier: `UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString`. And yes, device is same. Does anyone know what's the catch here?

EDIT: There is another problem, with iOS 10 that I cannot access Keychain item when phone is locked. I have set accessibility type `SSKeychain.setAccessibilityType(kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock)` and I have added entitlements for Key sharing, nothing.

Comment: I'm potentially facing the same issue, where I suspect that identifierForVendor has changed. This is a big problem for me since I'm using it as an encryption secret to encrypt the auth-token.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing update an app with TestFlight and experienced a strange behavior. After installing a previous version, we will see the newest version at the main screen of TestFlight with 2 UPDATE buttons.

- If I update by the LEFT UPDATE button, the vendor ID will be the same.
- If I update by the RIGHT UPDATE button, the vendor ID will change.
- If I go to Previous Builds > Show Builds > INSTALL (latest build), vendor ID will stay the same.

This is true at least for my current app. I am not sure if this may change in the future.